# Replacement for Sony PCM D50?

Tags: recording

My PCM D50 died on me after many faithful years of service. It got dropped in a bit of risky bicycle recording that caused a bit of damage about two months ago and only now stopped receiving any input regardless of how much I crank the input knob.

With the D50 being discontinued I'm curious as to what the next best option may be in terms of handhelds or am I better off ponying up for a bigger, better recording solution?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the obvious choice if you want the same good sound, low noise and adjustable mic angle
would be the D100? 
Once you start looking into separate mics, windscreens, etc, the price really goes up some. But so does flexibility, of course.

If I were you, I'd open up the D50 and look for what actual damage is in there. Maybe all it needs is re-heating a couple of solder joints (I'm thinking the volume pot here). Maybe mount it on something like a Manfrotto Magic Arm the next time you want to record your bicycle :-)